# Check all installed python versions on linux

Tags: python, conda

I use conda(anaconda) environments and wanted to test some syntax in py3.8.
Is there a way in which I can check all the installed python versions in my pc(across all conda envs).

I have tried

`ls -ls /usr/bin/python*`

but this doesn't include python installations in conda envs.

Answer (score 1):

One can search all Conda environments for the `python` package with

```bash
conda search --envs python
```

For each entry, this will give version, build, channel of origin, and the absolute location of the environment.